# Show that $2r^2-3$ is never a square, $r=2,3,...$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $2r^2-3$ is never a square, $r=2,3,...$

I know that no perfect square can have $2, 3, 7$, or $8$ as its last digit. I'm not sure how to do this with congruence/mod notation. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated. I also tried to assume it was equal to a perfect square and through some algebraic manipulations arrive at a contradiction, but that proved to be difficult. I'm curious to know if it can be done algebraically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2r^2-3$ is odd, so let $(2y+1)^2=4y^2+4y+1=2r^2-3$, then $4y^2+4y=2r^2-4$ so $2\mid r$ giving $r=2s\to y^2+y=2s^2-1$.  But $y^2+y$ is always even and $2s^2-1$ is always odd, so there is no solution in integers $y,r$.

Comment: This is awesome! I should have caught the fact that $2r^2-3$ is odd from the start. I'm confident I would have figured this out if I had done that. I was stuck on letting it equal $x^2$ and working from that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Each perfect square is congruent to $0$, $1$ or $4$ modulo $8$. But each number of the form $2n^2-3$ is congruent to $5$ or $7$ modulo $8$.

Comment: This might take me some time to understand. I'm new to this.

Comment: The first congruence means that $2n^2$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $8$ or that $8$ divides $2n^2$. That is, $2n^2=8x$ and so $n^2=4x$ for some integer $x$. How do I see that this is true? Am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: @ddswsd: this approach can be realized directly by squaring each of $4n,4n+1,4n+2,4n+3$ and taking the results modulo $8$.  Squaring $2n$ and $2n+1$ will give results part of the way there, but further logic may be required.

Comment: The approach in this answer is to consider the numbers modulo $8$ and their squares: $0\to 0, 1\to 1, 2\to 4, 3\to 9\equiv_8 1, 4\to 16\equiv_8 0,\dots$.

Comment: I don't understand yet, maybe I need to return to what it means for perfect squares to be congruent to $0, 1$, or $4$ modulo $8$ first and really understand it.

Comment: Suppose that $n$ is a perfect square. If $n$ is even, then $n=(2k)^2$ for some natural number $k$. But then $n=4k^2$, and therefore $n$ is a multiple of $4$. And if you divide a multiple of $4$ by $8$, the remainder is either $0$ or $4$. And, if $n$ is odd, $n=(2k-1)^2$ for some natural number $k$. But then $n=4k(k-1)+1$ and the number $k(k-1)$ is even, since it's the product of two consecutive natural numbers. So $n$ is a multiple of $8$ plus $1$. In other words, the remainder of the division of $n$ by $8$ is $1$. I hope that it's clear now.